# Android Multiple Canvas.Drawline

Tags: android

Hello All first post on Stack overflow!!

I am attempting to draw multiple lines on a canvas but using different colours. My problem is that the line colours are always the same as the last line in the array. I am drawing vertical lines progressively across the screen at 30Hz, similar to a bar chart without any spacing. I am calling view. Invalidate() for the view onDraw() to run and draw the lines.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (plotInfo == null)
            return;


        for (int i = 0; i < plotInfo.length; i++) {
            //paintlineinfo = String.valueOf( plotInfo[i].paintOfLine.getColor());
            canvas.drawLine(i, mDisplay.getHeight(), i, mDisplay.getHeight()-plotInfo[i].linePositionY, plotInfo[i].paintOfLine);
        }
    }
```

I believe I may to use Open GL but I am trying to avoid it for the moment unless anyone can point me in the right direction for a good article that may help me.

At some point i would like to make the lines multiple colours.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from there you ge the colour, try:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (plotInfo == null)
        return;

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);             

    for (int i = 0; i < plotInfo.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor( yourArrayOfColours.get(i) );
        canvas.drawLine(i, mDisplay.getHeight(), i, mDisplay.getHeight()-plotInfo[i].linePositionY, paint);
    }
}
```